# How come Q deferreds are so slow on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, deferred, promise, q

So I created this simple test server in Node.js
Whenever I do a direct response, I get **2200** requests/second (fast!).
When I only wrap a simple Q deferred around it, it drops to **580** requests/second (**4 times slower**!). Can anybody explain that huge difference?

```
// Requires
var server = require('http');
var q = require('q');

// Start server
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    // Comment out either of two below sections

// Without deferred
// 2200 reqs/second
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.write("test");
response.end();

// Q deferred
// 580 reqs/second
var deferred = q.defer();
deferred.promise.then(function() {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("test");
    response.end();
});
deferred.resolve();
}).listen(1234);
```

Comment: Apparently Q promises are really slow, I just read [this](http://dailyjs.com/2013/03/27/node-roundup/) which mentions the [Vow library](https://github.com/dfilatov/jspromise) which apparently is ~50 times faster than Q.

Comment: I'm checking https://github.com/medikoo/deferred at the moment as well, and it seems to have no overhead either (getting at 2200 reqs/second steadily). I'm just really curious why Q is so slow...

Comment: Browsing through the code I notice it uses `process.nextTick()` a lot, which might be slowing things down considerably.

Comment: How about [node-jquery](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery), I'd be interested to know how it compares performance-wise?

Comment: I'd interested to see these stats with the block just wrapped in a `process.nextTick`.

Comment: Thanks everybody! I might post up some results of different libraries on my blog. Will post here when it's done! And @MariuszNowak, if you could post that answer up, I'll accept it and close this question.

Comment: @Willem Sure, I posted it with a little edition, and removed my comment so it's not doubled.

Comment: The accepted answer gives the right info, but I think it's a shame that the authors of Q don't take this issue very seriously. I opened issue https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/297 on this very subject and was greeted with pretty significant hostility by the primary author Domenic. Granted, it was because he seems especially hostile to the use of coffeescript (how that can make someone so angry is beyond me), but after we got past that initial problem I don't think the authors took me very seriously. Based on the accepted answer in this thread, I don't think there is a way Q can address the

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reasons I'm aware of, are:

1. Q uses Object.freeze, and that slows V8 by magnitudes
2. Many nextTick calls (already mentioned in comments). This however shouldn't be that much of the case with latest Node.js version (v0.10), as there nextTick overhead is minimal.

Comment: Advice: use another deferred lib :)

Comment: Q responded to this problem some time ago—it no longer uses Object.freeze. We also unroll `nextTick` as much as possible. We do however still use `nextTick` frequently.

Comment: @mikeybaby173 https://github.com/medikoo/deferred is fast, but there might be many others out there that suit your needs better

Answer (score 21):

**Edit:** Performance has improved greatly since stacktraces have been turned off since Q 0.9.6. (They can be re-enabled for debugging with `Q.longStackSupport = true;`)

Original: Q promises are slow because they capture a full stack trace on every promise to help with debugging. This is very slow. You can turn them off with `Q.longStackJumpLimit = 0;` (which is likely to be the default in the next version). We found a roughly 30x speedup by turning them off. You can find out more here https://github.com/kriskowal/q#long-stack-traces

There's also been some [performance work on the nextTick implementation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/pull/195), but I think the above is the main reason.

Comment: My app just got 3 times faster with 1 line! *bows 3 times *

Comment: In Q 0.9.6, long stack traces are now off by default.

Comment: @Geert-Jan Mine got 10 times faster! This answer really helped me. I was wondering what was wrong and about to rewrite an important part of my app when I found this post. Thank you!